# how to impletement a progressbar which shows me the uploading % with xhr function

Tags: laravel, file-upload, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

```
let formData2 = new FormData();
                    formData2.append('_token', vm.response._token);
                    formData2.append('file', vm.response.content[i].path);
                    formData2.append('type', vm.response.content[i].type);
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        url: "page/file/create/upload/"+vm.response.topic_id,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formData2,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json', // what to expect back from the PHP script
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,

                        xhr: function() {
                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            console.log(xhr);
                            xhr.open('POST', this.url, false);
                            if (xhr.open) {
                                console.log("xhr port open");
                            }
                            if (xhr.upload) {
                                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.onProgress);
                                console.log("xhr.upload");
                            }
                            return xhr;
                          //  console.log(xhr);
                        },

                        success: function (title) {
                            console.log(" file upload in controller recieves: "+title);
                        },

                    })
                }
```

point : 1 >  this is a function written in "methods" in a vue page (file uploading practice project with laravel v5.5 + vue 1.0)

point : 2 > from my controller file is uploaded smoothly , has no issue with that.

point :3 > now i want to impletement a progressbar which shows me the uploading %

have tried xhr:function but do not know to fetch the uploading %...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below, it works in my side:

```
xhr : function() {
    var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    if(xhr.upload) {
        if(xhr instanceof window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            var percentage = 0;
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                if(e.lengthComputable) {
                    percentage = e.loaded/e.total;
                    percentage = parseInt(percentage * 100);
                    // Do what ever you want after here
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

Basically, I was using `xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr()` and `xhr.upload.addEventListener` progress to compute its progress percentage.

Hope this works.

Comment: percentage = parseInt(percentage * 100);
                                        // Do what ever you want after here
                                        console.log("percentage:"+percentage);     nothing has printed in console

Comment: in console i printed xhr. it shows :     upload
:
XMLHttpRequestUpload
onabort
:
null
onerror
:
null
onload
:
null
onloadend
:
null
onloadstart
:
null
onprogress
:
null
ontimeout
:
null

Comment: see my current function code above. i put  it as answare to show you.. thankz fr your time

Comment: yes my file has uploaded in server.... even the url also stored in table(myphpadmin) but in vue page i cann not get the upload %

Answer (score 0):

now my xhr function is look like this..  if i get the value of percentage. i will bind that with my progressbar value. but i can not get any upload %

```
xhr: function() {
                                var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                                console.log(xhr);
                                xhr.open('POST', this.url, false);
                                if (xhr.open) {
                                    console.log("xhr port open");
                                }
                                if (xhr.upload) {
                                    var percentage = 0;
                                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                                        if(e.lengthComputable) {
                                            percentage = e.loaded/e.total;
                                            percentage = parseInt(percentage * 100);
                                            // Do what ever you want after here
                                            console.log("percentage:"+percentage);
                                        }
                                    }, false);
                                }
                                return xhr;
                              //  console.log(xhr);
                            },
```

Comment: Man, have you tried to comment that `xhr.open('POST', this.url, false);`

Comment: And try to upload a large files too.

Comment: ƒ ()
ontimeout
:
null
readyState
:
4
response
:
"{"status":true}"
responseText
:
"{"status":true}"
responseType
:
""
responseURL
:
"http://localhost/contentbuilder/public/page/file/create/upload/8"
responseXML
:
null
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
timeout
:
0

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's working for me. happy me :)

```
xhr: function () {
                                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                                        console.log("% :" + percentComplete );
                                        $('.myprogress').text(percentComplete + '%');
                                        $('.myprogress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                                    }
                                }, false);
                                return xhr;
                            },
```

Comment: it is working. can any one check this and put a tick mark so other can easiely find and reuse it. thankz in advance